# How to define this set without knowing the $x$ values?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, definition

Take the function $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and:

$$
y = f(x) = \sin(x)
$$

It is easy to define the set of points where the function is larger or equal to $0.5$:

$$
A=\{x\mid f(x)\geq0.5\}
$$

If we plot the function and use a different color for the set it looks for example like this. Blue are the points that are not in $A$ and red are the points that are in $A$. But this is not the set that I want.

[image]

The set I want is only the fourth red subset in the first image (lets call it $B$). This looks like (red in $B$, blue not in $B$):

[image]

Of course if we know the $x$ values where the subset starts and ends we can define it very easily:

$$
B=\{x\mid \frac{13 \pi}{6}\leq x \leq \frac{17 \pi}{6}\}
$$

But this definition has a problem: I need to know the $x$ values. When $f$ is not like in this example but a very difficult function I can't use such definition anymore.

Without the $x$ values it is difficult but assume I know more about $B$: for example it contains the value $7.5$ and it does not consist of "disjoint" sets. I am looking for a definition that uses these information instead of the $x$ values.

But the definition must also work in higher dimensions. For example for

$$
z = f(x,y) = \sin(|x| + |y|)
$$

Now the set $A$ would be

$$
A=\{x,y\mid f(x, y)\geq0.5\}
$$

Blue: not in $A$, Red: in $A$

[image]

Again this is not the set that I want. I want instead $B$, for example (red in $B$, blue not in $B$):

[image]

I can define $B$ with the $x,y$ values for example:

$$
B=\{x,y \mid f(x,y)\geq 0.5\text{ and } 4\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq 9\}
$$

But I don't want to use those values because they may be very hard to find. I also can't use a definition like:

$$
B=\{x,y \mid \forall t\in[0,1]\colon f(t \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} +(1-t)\begin{pmatrix}7.5\\0\end{pmatrix})\ge0.5\ \}
$$

because it doesn't give me the correct set:

[image]

You can see that the left side is missing with the definition.

What is the correct way to define $B$ without using the $x$ (or $x,y$) values that also works in higher dimensions?

Comment: It seems that your loci are like $\sin(\phi)\ge0.5$ where $\phi$ is a multivariate function. Then the condition to select inside a specific period is simply $\sin(\phi)\ge0.5\land 2k\pi\le\phi\le2(k+1)\pi$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for the comment, just to clarify the $\sin$ is just an example. It could be a different function (not even periodic).

Comment: With a different, nonperiodic function, there is no way to answer your question. It is underspecified.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Could you please explain why you think that is the case? I.e. what is for example the answer by Zuy missing?

Comment: Zuy added his own hypothesis. Realize that your question is incomplete.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Could you help me realizing what is missing to make the question complete? Which hypothesis was added by Zuy? You mean the assumption that the set is connected? Isn't that covered by the assumption that $B$ does not consist of disjoint sets?

Answer (score 1):

If your function is of the form $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ (or some subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb R$), you are interested in the connected component of $\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid f(x)\geq a\}$ which contains some fixed $x_0$. This may be defined by
$$\bigcup\{U\subseteq\mathbb R^n\mid\text{$U$ connected, $x_0\in U$, $f(x)\geq a$ for each $x\in U$}\}.$$

Comment: Two questions, why do we need the $\bigcup$? Shouldn't there be only one such $U$? And can "connected" be defined with equations/inequalities instead using the word?

Comment: Taking the union ensures that the resulting set is maximal (with respect to inclusion). Concerning your second question, I cannot think of a workaround. You may want to look up the definition of a connected subset of $\mathbb R^n$ though, if you wish not to use that word.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want the set of all $x$ such that $f(x)\ge 0.5$ and for all $\xi $ between $x$ and $7.5$, also $f(\xi)\ge 0.5$:
$$ B=\bigl\{\,x\in\Bbb R\bigm| \forall t\in[0,1]\colon f(tx+(1-t)7.5)\ge0.5\,\bigr\}.$$

Comment: Unfortunatly that doesn't work for higher dimensions. I have updated the question, can we make this work for the new example?